# Use variable NAME as value in PHP

Tags: php, variables, introspection

Not sure how to ask this without rambling about preprocessors in C, but I will try:

Is there a way in PHP, to use the **name** of a variable as a string or value.

Such that instead of calling function like this,

```
$somevar = 'whatever';

fun('somevar', $somevar);
```

you can call it like this:

```
fun(<magic:$somevar>, $somevar);
```

or even, dare I say it, *like this*:

```
fun($somevar);
```

and the fun() would itself deduce both the value ('whatever'), and the name ('somevar') of the variable. (In C, it could be done with a preprocessor #define.)

<sub>"magic" above is of course a place holder for the magic syntax in PHP I am looking for which will help me do this. I guess it could be made somehow with eval()?  But people keep telling me not to use eval.</sub>

Someone hinted that introspection might somehow do the trick. Any leads there would be welcome.

Comment: I got some hints about ReflectionParameters by passers-by, but you deleted your comments.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Amigable are you looking for something like returning the variable name as a value.?

Comment: @sberry, more succinct code, I have lots of variable names which are always the same as that string.  Stupid to type the same thing twice.

Comment: @ravz, I think that's what I am looking for.

Comment: @amigable i have reposted my answer if that would help you give a hint.

Comment: `fun(ltrim('$somevar','$'), $somevar);` isn't what you want?

Comment: @goldenparrot, from the description, technically yes, but actually not quite, what happens if I mistype, fun(ltrim('$somevarr', '$'), $somevar); is that the PHP gives no help at all. If the first argument was just a variable, the parser could warn that $somevarr was undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. PHP's scoping rules prevent you from doing that. The only way would be through a pre processor (as you are aware) or by introspecting the code, which would be kind of the same thing. PHP has a built-in tokenizer, that you can use to parse a file with. You can use `debug_backtrace` to find out which files to parse through. It's going to be a really messy and inefficient thing to do though, so you would probably be better off rethinking what you're doing.

Comment: Elan - "I don't wanna sell you death sticks." troelskn - "You want to go home and rethink your life." Amigable - "I wanna go home and rethink my life."

Comment: ;) - Not knowing your use case, I may be off, but it sounds like you might want to use an array for this, somehow?

Comment: I think I will just use fun('x', $x);  at least it's very readable and straightforward and easy to spot errors visually.

Comment: If it works, then I concur. Verbose is usually better than clever.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function var_name(&$var, $scope=0)
{
    $old = $var;
    if (($key = array_search($var = 'unique'.rand().'value', !$scope ? $GLOBALS : $scope)) && $var = $old) return $key;  
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite what he is looking for

Comment: @Mythril i think he wants the variable name to be as a string. This function returns that. or can u please explain where I'm wrong so that i correct it.

Comment: Run this in the same scope as your function `$x = 5; $y = 5; echo var_name($x), "\n"; echo var_name($y), "\n";`

Comment: also, this would utterly fail when trying to use it on a local inside of a function

Comment: @Mythril yes i will try to find a solution. Thanks

Comment: Also it loops through a lot of variables to find the one, which is kind of bad from a performance perspective.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant have you checked for get_defined_vars().

Comment: It would also involve a lot of looping through arrays.

Comment: Is that limited somehow in scope to just the function var_name()?

Comment: Ah, you overwrite the value with something random. Evil and clever. :-)  +1

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant >>Is that limited somehow in scope << sorry couldn't get you

Comment: I mean, if I set another variable named $var someplace else in the PHP file, will it somehow collide if I am unlucky?

Comment: If nothing better performance wise shows up, I will eventually accept this answer, because your function works. But I won't use it, it's too weird. :-)

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

The probably explain it better than I can, I think this is what you're looking for?

Alright, before you call the function do the following:

```
$var= "variableName";
$$var = "variableValue";
fun($var);
```

Now within the function definition for fun:

```
function fun($parameter)
{
    global $$parameter;
    echo $parameter; //echos the variableName
    echo $$parameter; //echos the variableValue
}
```

Comment: Either, no it's NOT what I am looking for, OR I don't understand what that page says.

Comment: @RedHydra: I would have given the same answer

Comment: @Double so you would also have pointed to a page and not actually write an answer. ;-)

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant I've updated my answer, I'm pretty sure this will work for you, let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: How will that help me write:   $clevername = 'something';  fun($clevername);    ....... and the fun() knowing both 'clevername' and 'something'

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Edited to add a way you can use this in your exact use case.

Comment: In my case I would have to write:   $var = 'from';  $$var = $from; fun($from);    --- this would just be a roundabout way of writing fun('from', $from');